# NSURLCache and .svg files

Tags: ios, nsurlcache

I am caching locally some of the larger files required for a UIWebView and have a subclass of NSURLCache with a custom implementation to help serve these files.

```
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponseForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
```

I am using this to hijack the requests and return a locally stored copy of the files (mainly t

The body of cachedResponseForRequest:request (without the boiler plate) is essentially:

```
// logic to figure out what the local file is, load it into a NSData object (f)
NSURLResponse *r = [[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:request.URL MIMEType:mimetype expectedContentLength:[f length] textEncodingName:nil];
NSCachedURLResponse *cr = [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:r data:f] ;
[super storeCachedResponse:cr forRequest:request];
return cr;
```

This works correctly for all of the cached content apart from a single svg image.  When the svg image is attempted to load it will proceed through cachedResponseForRequest:request, build a NSCachedURLResponse object and return it.

However the next thing the application does is download the file from the remote server and then any subsequent request are served from the cache.  We dont want to download the file remotely as its relatively large and impacts performance.

Does the NSURLCache deal with .svg files differently to other filetypes?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of files that will be handled by the NSUrlCache can be influenced by the parameters when you initialize the cache with:

initWithMemoryCapacity:(NSUInteger)memoryCapacity diskCapacity:(NSUInteger)diskCapacity diskPath:(NSString *)diskPath

The maximum file size is related to the memoryCapacity. You should set that to at least 10 (why?) times the maximum file size that you want to handle.

I have tried this with files up to 15MB using https://github.com/evermeer/EVURLCache